# Osascript always returns error Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x7fa3f42032e0

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, osascript

Osascript in terminal always returns this error for the simplest function.
When i run the script in ApplescriptEditor it runs fine…

e.g.:

`$: osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm" to display dialog "Hello World"'`

```
2014-01-22 11:59:19.822 osascript[665:707] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x7fa3f42032e0 </Library/ScriptingAdditions/AeroFSFinderExtension.osax> (not loaded)
osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition
"/Library/ScriptingAdditions/AeroFSFinderExtension.osax" declares no loadable handlers.
button returned:OK
```

I already reinstalled XCode and CLL (Using Appcleaner)

Does anybody know how to fix this error? (Or at least silence it…)

I'm on 10.8.5

Comment: Looks like "AeroFSFinderExtension.osax" is incompatible with that OS X. Try to update to a compatible version or remove it from /Library/ScriptingAdditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is `/Library/ScriptingAdditions/AeroFSFinderExtension.osax`?

Looks like it's a broken scripting addition, and if it's not actually needed, simply try to remove the file (you'll need admin privileges), then run `osascript` again.

Comment: Wow, that was simple. And nothing broke (yet).
I thought AeroFSFinderExtension.osax had something to do with XtraFinder, but seems that's not the case.
Thanks!

Comment: @FlorianSchrödl XtraFinder's osax is named "XtraFinder.osax". AeroFSFinderExtension.osax is eventually from here: https://www.aerofs.com/